# Stop Intellisense display timeout

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, timeout, intellisense

I'm using VS 2010 Ultimate for C++ coding, with no changes to any settings.

If I type  **MyClass->** Intellisense shows popup list of MyClass members. Initially the first item in the popup is highlighted, but I can **single**-click to move the highlight.

A "child" popup to the right of the highlighted item shows the function declaration line for the class member *and* any comment lines that immediately precede it in the relevant header file. Which is very helpful, thank you Microsoft.

**BUT** after a few seconds that "child" popup times out - sometimes when I'm still tring to read a lengthy series of comment lines from the header.

Is there any way to stop that child popup from fading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in Microsoft Connect:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/328852/tooltips-in-intellisense-disappear-unwantedly

> Posted by Microsoft on 4/26/2010 at 3:38 PM
>
> Hi TimwiTerby,
> As Sean wrote in his previous comment, this was postponed so that we could *consider* it for a future version of Visual Studio. As you've noticed, we did not implement this suggestion for VS 2010. I'm sorry to hear that you're disappointed, but I hope you'll also understand that it's very rare that something is truly a one-line fix, especially when considering dev time, test costs, and risk of introducing another bug.
>
> Thanks again for your feedback,
> Brittany Behrens
> Program Manager, VS Platform
> blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio

Comment: Thanks RedX - I can't argue with that (though Hans Passants's post about increasing the mouse double-click time should also be mentioned in despatches).

Answer (score 4):

Control Panel + Mouse.  Increase the double-click time.  This is the base timer for a lot of 'how agile is the user' timers.  Including the default tooltip autopop delay timer interval.  I'll avoid making jokes about it :)

Comment: Thanks for a cunning "semi-workaround". But if I can only "accept" one answer, I'll have to go with RedX below - and wait for MS to ship the appropriate update.

Comment: I just now saw your nick.  Too funny, avoiding making jokes required angelic amounts of restraint :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go ahead and doubt that this is configurable. If it were, there would be an option in `Tools::Options::Text Editor::<Language>::Intellisense`, and there is none.

Comment: I'm afraid, you're right. As I know, there is only Options > All Languages> Statement Completion - Parameter information (Check/Uncheck).

Comment: @nubm: Well, there are _some_ Intellisense options under certain languages (C# at least, AFAIK), but none of them address any timeouts.

Comment: Well, this Q has been around for a while without getting the kind of answer I was hoping for, so I suppose it's not going anywhere.I still think most likely the MS programmer who coded this particular display probably used a variable stored in the registry, to control how long to leave it on-screen, even if the team never got around to providing a config option for changing the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

VisualAssist from WholeTomato is your answer. It does solve your particular problem, and it does a lot more to Intellisense. It's extremely useful. It costs $$$ but hey, so does your version of VS.

Comment: I have VAX and it's really worth it's money. Intellisense++++ at least. Well i got my MSDN for free from the Universtiy ;-)

Comment: I'm glad you're one of the initiated. :) I'm hitting the cap again today, so this has nothing to do with reputation: upvoting on SO is just as important as adding comments and answers.